# unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app, I use a very large amount of code that I copied from Apple's SpeakHere example, and when I run the app on an iPhone device it spits out this error about a hundred times before loading the XIB:

```
unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022
```

It also prints these errors:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/eamonford/Desktop/Sleep Blaster touch/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Sleep Blaster touch.app/Sleep Blaster touch" (file not found).    
warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "Sleep Blaster touch" for breakpoint 1.
```

However, when I run the app in the Simulator there are no errors at all. Also, I know the errors are coming from some part of the code that I got from SpeakHere, because Apple's own example produces the same errors, and my app didn't produce these errors before I added the SpeakHere code.

Does anyone have some idea of what these errors mean or how I can trace them? Thanks!

Comment: I get these errors too... what's up with that?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first warning, this appears to be a known issue in SDK 3.1 (I'm assuming you're using 3.1, I'd never seen this error with other versions). If you try compiling with a 3.0 target, that should resolve it.

Comment: Hmm, well the device is running 3.1, but I'm compiling for SDK 3.0, and it's still producing the errors... Would the device need to be running 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error after upgrading to Snow Leopard, but before upgrading the Developer tools.

If you haven't already, go download and install the new Xcode and SDKs.