# Symbolic Constant in Xcode

Tags: c

I'm learning C through The C Programming Language 2nd Edition and it refers to symbolic constants where you use `#define` before `main()` to assign a label to a value.

This is the program I am trying to use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOWER 0
#define UPPER 300
#define STEP 20

main()
{
    int fahr;

    for (fahr = LOWER; fahr <= UPPER; fahr = fahr + STEP)
    {
        printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
    }
}
```

Printing a table of Fahrenheit Celsius conversions. However This code when compiled in xcode using the c tool gives me the response `unable to read unknown load command` referring to the line starting with `for`. I've tried retyping the program but it still hasn't worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When writing code just prefix it with 4 spaces - don't write it as HTML. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine. There's something wrong with your XCode setup (may be related: [unable to read unknown load command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101794/unable-to-read-unknown-load-command-0x80000022).

```
cristi:tmp diciu$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOWER    0
#define UPPER    300
#define STEP 20

main()
{
    int fahr;

    for (fahr = LOWER; fahr <= UPPER; fahr = fahr + STEP)
        printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
}
cristi:tmp diciu$ gcc test.c
cristi:tmp diciu$ ./a.out 
  0  -17.8
 20   -6.7
 40    4.4
[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in XCode - the only warning/error I got was

> Control reaches end of non-void function

As defining `main()` defaults to int it should return something, eg. 0 for a successful program. Convention suggests that 0 means a program runs correctly and anything else is an error.

Better to define

```
int main()
{ 
    /* code */ 
    return 0;
}
```

as your main function. But this is a digression - see [diciu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974060/symbolic-constant-problem-in-xcode/1974111#1974111) for a potential explanation of your problem